# How do I fix "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int' "?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Hi I just need a code for an Hand degree in live camera, on Google there are some projects but with the head. No matter what I change the code returns me, this error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Here is my code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWL85.png)

```
    `contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(fg_mask_bb,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
    area = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]  
    
    if area < 3700 or 10000 < area :continue
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    center = (int(rect[0][0]),int(rect[0][1])) 
    width = int(rect[1][0])
    height = int(rect[1][1])
    angle = int(rect[2])
    
    if width < height:
        angle = 90 - angle
    else:
        angle = -angle`
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? You are currently comparing a list to a number (i.e. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] < 3700)

Comment: As the error message says, `area` is a list which you cannot compare against a single integer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33715004/edit) to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if every item in the list is > 3700 or < 10000, you could do it this way:

```
for n in area:
    if n < 3700 or n > 10000: continue
```

Alternatively, make sure these entries don't even end up in area:

```
area = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours if cv2.contourArea(c) >= 3700 and cv2.contourArea(c) <= 10000]
```